# Noobslab theme in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: 16.10

Noobslab Mac theme shows error while installing in Ubuntu 16.10, when I use below command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7 
sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v7
```

noobs lab mac theme is not supported in Ubuntu 16.10?

Comment: Yes , I got that.....

http://www.noobslab.com/2016/11/macbuntu-1610-transformation-pack-for.html

Comment: What error exactly?

Comment: Noobslab PPAs haven't been updated in a while and maintainer haven't answered requests I have made, so . . .just saying, don't be too optimistic about them. You're better off downloading deb file of older releases and installing manually